# How to fill up an IOBufferMemoryDescriptor with data

Tags: c++, iokit, ipados, driverkit

I'm using DriverKit in my iPadOS.

I'm trying to create a `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` and add the data I've got in an `OSData` object.

I'm creating the `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` with:

```
    ret = ivars->interface->CreateIOBuffer(kIOMemoryDirectionOut,
                                           length,
                                           &myBuffer);
```

Although I think it can be created with this too:

```
    IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create(kIOMemoryDirectionOut, length, 0, &mybuffer);
```

How do I add the data from my `OSData` object. I've seen examples of:

```
IOMemoryDescriptor *buffer = IOMemoryDescriptor::withAddress((void*)firmwareData->getBytesNoCopy(), firmwareData->getLength(), kIODirectionOut);
```

(from [How to use deviceRequest of IOUSBHostDevice / IOUSBHostInterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935353/how-to-use-devicerequest-of-iousbhostdevice-iousbhostinterface/59951271#59951271) )

But that method doesn't seem to work in DriverKit.

I've also tried Mapping the Buffer:

```
    uint64_t bufferAddress;
    uint64_t bufferLength;
    ret = myBuffer->Map(0, 0, 0, 0, &bufferAddress, &bufferLength);
```

and then copying the data with:

```
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(bufferAddress), inputOsData->getBytesNoCopy(), length);
```

But this would always make the driver to crash when tries to run the memcpy

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** On first reading I missed that you used `kIOMemoryDirectionOut`. In my experience, this doesn't seem to work reliably for buffer memory descriptors, probably because write-only mapping isn't available on most CPU architectures. Use `kIOMemoryDirectionInOut`.

**Main answer:**

To obtain a pointer to the `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor`'s internal buffer, you need to use the [`GetAddressRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iobuffermemorydescriptor/3180453-getaddressrange) method. The returned `IOAddressSegment` struct's `address` field can then be `reinterpret_cast` to `void*` and filled with `memcpy` or similar.

The API is rather clumsy, so I recommend wrapping it into a helper function. I have something like this:

```
djt_buffer djt_iobmd_get_byte_range(IOBufferMemoryDescriptor* buffer)
{
    IOAddressSegment range = {};
    kern_return_t ret = buffer->GetAddressRange(&range);
    if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess)
        return djt_buffer{};

    return djt_buffer { reinterpret_cast<void*>(range.address), range.length };
}
```

where `djt_buffer` is defined as:

```
struct djt_buffer
{
    void* bytes;
    size_t size;
};
```

Note that the `CreateIOBuffer` method of creating the buffer is preferable when you're going to use the buffer for USB I/O, as it's supposed to prevent the use of bounce buffers. The generic `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create()` variant is fine for other purposes.

Note also that every memory descriptor creation, every call to `GetAddressRange` or `GetLength`, etc. requires a round trip to the kernel, so I recommend re-using/pooling descriptors instead of destroying/recreating them for every IO operation. You can also cache the address pointer and length of each descriptor in your driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @pmdj
I'm a bit confused, in order to get the buffer address I can use both methods? The one created by you: djt_iobmd_get_byte_range or CreateMapping and then GetAddress(); and GetLength();?

I tried both and they seems to fail in the same point in the memcpy. The first one I do:     memcpy(bufferInfo.bytes, &inputChar, bufferInfo.size);
using the map I have to do a reinterpret_cast so:     memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(bufferAddress), &inputChar, length);

Comment: Interestingly if I use:     
`IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create(kIOMemoryDirectionOut, length, 0, &myBuffer);`
instead of `CreateIOBuffer`, it works fine... 

With both ways btw :)

Comment: @xarly Ahh, yes I missed that you used `kIOMemoryDirectionOut`. You need to use `kIOMemoryDirectionInOut`. I'm surprised it works when using `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create`. Note that if you use `CreateMapping` you MUST release the mapping once done or you will cause leaks. Passing the mapping back and forth between kernel and dext will also be more expensive than just using `GetAddressRange()`, so there's no reason to use 
`CreateMapping` on **Buffer** memory descriptors. (Plain `IOMemoryDescriptor`s don't have `GetAddressRange` however, and do not come pre-mapped.)

Comment: nice, that works!!, I wish Apple gets the documentation a bit better, imposible to find out that was the problem. Thanks a lot again and Merry Christmas :)